# Alternating replace of substrings

Tags: c#, string, substring, markdown

I was wondering if there is any way that I can replace substrings within a string but alternate between the string to replace them with. I.E, match all occurences of the string `"**"` and replace the first occurence with `"<strong>"` and the next occurence with `"</strong>"` (And then repeat that pattern).

The input would be something like this: `"This is a sentence with **multiple** strong tags which will be **strong** upon output"`

And the output returned would be: `"This is a sentence with <strong>multiple</strong> strong tags which will be <strong>strong</strong> upon output"`

Comment: You can use `IndexOf` with a start index in a loop.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I haven't really used IndexOf that often, will take a look into it but would you have any method of implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string toReplace = "This is a sentence with **multiple** strong tags which will be **strong** upon output";
        int index = 0;
        string replaced = Regex.Replace(toReplace, @"\*\*", (m) => {
            index++;
            if (index % 2 == 1) {
                return "<strong>";
            } else {
                return "</strong>";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paolo I just used this again and realised that the code can be shortened and looks a little better if you replace the `if` statement with `return index % 2 == 1 ? "<strong>" : "</strong>";`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would be to actually regex for `**(content)**` rather than just `**`. You then replace that by `<strong>(content)</strong>` and you're done.

You may also want to check out MarkdownSharp at https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp, since that is really what you seem to want to use.

Comment: This is the cleanest approach, +1.

Comment: I have looked at MarkDownSharp but I only want the bolding for the input, not so much the whole features. I may start using it when it becomes requested more often

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to solve this:

```
string sentence = "This is a sentence with **multiple** strong tags which will be **strong** upon output";

var expression = new Regex(@"(\*\*([a-z]+)\*\*)");

string result = expression.Replace(sentence, (m) => string.Concat("<strong>", m.Groups[2].Value, "</strong>"));
```

This approach will handle syntax errors automatically (think of a string like `This **word should be **strong**`).

Answer (score -1):

Try it out

```
var sourceString = "This is a sentence with **multiple** strong tags which will be **strong** upon output";
var resultString = sourceString.Replace(" **","<strong>");
resultString = sourceString.Replace("** ","</strong>");
```

cheers,

Comment: that obviously doesn't fit his spec.

Comment: This will mess up if the spaces do not exist, and there is no reason they should.

Comment: This works for the input that I specified but if the starting group of `**`'s is at the start of the string, you have problems

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use Regular expressions to match the pattern and replace it, it's quite easy.

Comment: Too simplistic for an answer.  Please provide an example in code that hasn't already been provided.